# I am using thymeleaf in my code and here the return type is String but i want return type like : Public response abc(){...ret response}

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String helloForm()
{
    return "helloform";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String hello(HttpServletRequest request,Model model) {

    String name = request.getParameter("name");

    if (name == null) {
        name = "world";
    }
  // do what you want to code....

  model.addAttribute("message",HelloMessage.getMessage(name));
   // return "<h1>" + HelloMessage.getMessage(name) + "</h1>";
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: but i want return type as response like : Public response abc(){...ret response} help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

try @ResponseBody at method and set view name in model.

Comment: didn't get your solution .. what is view name ????? I am new in thymeleaf ... Thanks for reply !!!

Comment: ModelAndView class.

public String hello(HttpServletRequest request,ModelAndView mav) {
  mav.setViewName("viewName");
}